# R array indexing for multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have a simple array indexing question for multi-dimensional arrays in R. I am doing a lot of simulations that each give a result as a matrix, where the entries are classified into categories. So for example a result looks like

```
aresult<-array(sample(1:3, 6, replace=T), dim=c(2,5), 
               dimnames=list(
                 c("prey1", "prey2"), 
                 c("predator1", "predator2", "predator3", "predator4", "predator5")))
```

Now I want to store the results of my experiments in a 3D-matrix, where the first two dimension are the same as in `aresult` and the third dimension holds the number of experiments that fell into each category. So my arrays of counts should look like

```
Counts<-array(0, dim=c(2, 5, 3), 
              dimnames=list(
                c("prey1", "prey2"), 
                c("predator1", "predator2", "predator3", "predator4", "predator5"),
                c("n1", "n2", "n3")))
```

and after each experiment I want to increment the numbers in the third dimension by 1, using the values in `aresults` as indexes.

How can I do that without using loops?

Comment: you might be looking for `abind`, from the `abind` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a typical job for matrix indexing. By subsetting `Counts` with a three column matrix, each row specifying the indices of an element we want to extract, we are free to extract and increment any elements we like.

```
# Create a map of all combinations of indices in the first two dimensions
i <- expand.grid(prey=1:2, predator=1:5)

# Add the indices of the third dimension
i <- as.matrix( cbind(i, as.vector(aresult)) )

# Extract and increment
Counts[i] <- Counts[i] + 1
```