# Storing model predictions in a multi-dimensional array in R, indexing changes structure

Tags: r, arrays

I am fitting a large number of models and making predictions from them to plot. To me the most efficient way of doing this should be to create a 3D array and overwrite each matrix with the corresponding predictions. However, when I use bracket indexing to overwrite the array the array changes form.

```
library(tidyverse)

# The data
dat <- data.frame(x=seq(0,10,1),
                  y=seq(0,5,0.5)^2,
                  y2=c(12,7,13,14,18,15,19,23,25,23,24))
# a look at the data
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),color='red') +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y2),color='blue')

# Fit some models
mod.list <- list()

mod.list[[1]] <- glm(y~x+I(x^2), 
                     data = dat,
                     family = gaussian()) 
mod.list[[2]] <- glm(y2~x+I(x^2), 
                     data = dat,
                     family = gaussian()) 
# make predictions
new = data.frame(x = seq(0,10,1)) # data to predict on
# Create array to hold predictions
all.preds <- array(data = 0,
                   dim = c(10,3,2))
# Overwrite prediction array per Ritchie's comment
all.preds <- array(data = 0,
                   dim = c(NROW(new),3,2))
dimnames(all.preds)[[2]] <- c('x','fit_link','se_link')

for (i in 1:2) {
  preds <-  bind_cols(new, setNames(as_tibble(predict(mod.list[[i]], 
                                                      newdata = new, 
                                                      se.fit = TRUE)[1:2]), # return standard errors
                                    c('fit_link','se_link'))) 
  all.preds[ , ,i] <- preds
}
```

This seems like it should be relatively straightforward, however, I cannot locate others who have done similar operations. Certainly, there must be something I am missing. This is the closest I found but I think it's easier to do in a for loop?
[R array indexing for multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379540/r-array-indexing-for-multi-dimensional-arrays)

EDIT:
I found I can do this with lists...still maybe not the best?

```
all.preds <- list()
# make predictions
new = data.frame(x = seq(0,10,1))


for (i in 1:2) {
  all.preds[[i]] <-  bind_cols(new, setNames(as_tibble(predict(mod.list[[i]], 
                                                      newdata = new, 
                                                      se.fit = TRUE)[1:2]), # return standard errors
                                    c('fit_link','se_link'))) 
  # all.preds[ , ,i] <- preds
  
}
```

Comment: (1) If your goal is to plot the data with ggplot2 then it is preferable to store the result in a list of data frames. (2) Your attempt to place the predictions in an array doesn't work because you are defining the array to have 10 rows but your prediction object has 11 rows AND the prediction object is a data frame where it needs to be a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. I don't load package `tidyverse` since the code is base R only. The new data `new` is corrected to have only 10 rows.

```r
# Create array to hold predictions
all.preds <- array(data = 0, dim = c(10,3,2))
dimnames(all.preds)[[2]] <- c('x','fit_link','se_link')

# make predictions
new = data.frame(x = seq(1, 10, 1))

for(i in seq_along(mod.list)) {
  preds <- predict(mod.list[[i]], newdata = new, se.fit = TRUE)[1:2]
  all.preds[, 1, i] <- new[["x"]]
  all.preds[ , 2:3, i] <- matrix(unlist(preds), ncol = 2)
}
all.preds
#> , , 1
#> 
#>        x fit_link      se_link
#>  [1,]  1     0.25 9.671887e-16
#>  [2,]  2     1.00 7.645017e-16
#>  [3,]  3     2.25 7.541841e-16
#>  [4,]  4     4.00 8.083363e-16
#>  [5,]  5     6.25 8.350338e-16
#>  [6,]  6     9.00 8.083363e-16
#>  [7,]  7    12.25 7.541841e-16
#>  [8,]  8    16.00 7.645017e-16
#>  [9,]  9    20.25 9.671887e-16
#> [10,] 10    25.00 1.396718e-15
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>        x fit_link  se_link
#>  [1,]  1 10.87552 1.303368
#>  [2,]  2 12.69044 1.030230
#>  [3,]  3 14.45175 1.016326
#>  [4,]  4 16.15944 1.089301
#>  [5,]  5 17.81352 1.125278
#>  [6,]  6 19.41399 1.089301
#>  [7,]  7 20.96084 1.016326
#>  [8,]  8 22.45408 1.030230
#>  [9,]  9 23.89371 1.303368
#> [10,] 10 25.27972 1.882195
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question as written. I did update the original post to include an array with 11 rows which solved my problem as well and includes all rows of my predictions.

Comment: @dandrews I've just noticed, in the loop `for(i in seq_along(mod.list))` is better, will edit.

Comment: That's a great update, thanks! This fixes any issue if I add models so the for loop doesn't need to be updated.